# Can I change the input color of my Bash prompt to something different than the terminal default?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, dotfiles

My default terminal color is gray, and that's fine.

My Bash prompt displays a bunch of colors, and this works fine:

```
PS1="${COLOR_RED}\u${COLOR_WHITE}@${COLOR_RED}${COMPUTERNAME} ${COLOR_BLUE}\w${GITPROMPT} ${COLOR_RESET}"
```

But the text I type in, at the end of the prompt, is gray. I want it to be white (ANSI code "[37m").

If I add a COLOR_WHITE at the end of the prompt, instead of the COLOR_RESET, then the default terminal color changes to white until it is reset. This makes a weird effect of some gray text, with some white text bleeding through at the top.

How can I change the "input text" color of the Bash prompt, to something other than the terminal default color?

Comment: Might found useful [How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux) and [Bash Prompt Generator](http://ezprompt.net/).

Answer (score 8):

**Simply** add the following line:

```
export PS1=" \[\033[34m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[31m\]\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

**Preview:**

[image]

These are my preferred colors. You can customize each part of the prompt's color by changing `m` codes (e.g., `34m`) which are ANSI color codes.

**List of ANSI color codes:**

- Black: 30m
- Red: 31m
- Green: 32m
- Yellow: 33m
- Blue: 34m
- Purple: 35m
- Cyan: 36m
- White: 37m

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. It is simpler:

```
export PS1="\e[0;32m\t \e[32;1m\u@\h:\e[0;36m\w\e[0m$ "
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything when I add it to my bash_profile

Comment: What shell are you using?  (echo $SHELL).  This only works for bash.  Also you can try typing it directly on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your terminal emulator's settings.

It appears you are using [iTerm2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2) (if you are on iTerm, I suggest looking at iTerm2), so:

*Settings* → *Profiles* → *Your Profile* → *Color*. Under 'basic colors', adjust 'foreground'.

For just changing the color of the input text, in Z shell (`zsh`) you could use a

```
preexec () { echo -ne "\e[0m" }
```

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268836/zsh-change-prompt-input-color)

I have found a hack-ish way to try this with Bash:

> Not natively, but it can be hacked up using the DEBUG trap. [This code](http://www.twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/preexec.bash.txt) sets up preexec and `precmd` functions similar to zsh. The command line is passed as a single argument to preexec.
>
> Here is a simplified version of the code to set up a precmd function that is executed before running each command.

```
preexec () { :; }
preexec_invoke_exec () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    local this_command=$(history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g");
    preexec "$this_command"
}
```

> trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG 
> This trick is due to [Glyph Lefkowitz](http://glyf.livejournal.com/63106.html); thanks to [bcat] for locating the original author.
>
> http://www.macosxhints.com/dlfiles/preexec.bash.txt

[Source 2](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command)

Comment: I understand that. However I'm trying to change the "input text" color to something _different_ than the foreground. Probably not a way to do that, but figured i'd ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my installation of [Debian 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_8_(Jessie)) (Jessie) I already have this, but it is commented by default. It is

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

I just uncommented the line that says `force_color_prompt=yes`.

If you didn't already have this in your *.bashrc* file then you can copy this and paste it in yours.